# How to assign a java variable in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am accessing a database through JSP and I want to have the value stored in a java variable. Here is the code

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
     SELECT sno FROM sites WHERE name = '<%= request.getParameter("well_number")%>' ;
</sql:query>

 <%! 
    int well_no ;
    int site_no ;
    int field_no ;
  %>

  <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">

  </c:forEach>
```

So I am asking how to set the value of 'sno' which is extracted from the database to the java variable site_sno ;

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why you are calling java code in your JSP page ? the best solution is to work with bean (MVC architecture)

Comment: set the row value into your java variable 
site_no=row

Comment: no it is not working !! On the web page it is getting printed as site_sno = row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know the background, but you should avoid scriplet in jsp, and use only tag.

If you need a variable for some later manipulation, you could just use

```
<c:set var="site_sno" value="${row.someData}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
     SELECT sno FROM sites WHERE name = '<%= request.getParameter("well_number")%>' ;
</sql:query>

 <%! 
    int well_no ;
    ArrayList<Integer>site_numbers=new ArrayList<>();
    int field_no ;
  %>


  <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
     site_numbers.add(row);
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: The query would return only one value ( count = 1 ) then also do I have to use ArrayList ?